# Requested URL changes when using custom rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm having basically the same problem as question #44117. I have a custom rewrite rule set using add_rewrite_rule, but when the user goes to the page, the entered url changes and the value is lost.

User enters: membership/member-profile/profile-name/

And is forwarded to: membership/member-profile/

Here's my rewrite code:

```
function profile_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('membership/member-profile/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=member-profile&profile=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'profile_rewrite');
```

I've been researching for hours, and while I've found others with a similar problem, there has never been a definite solution.

Maybe it's a problem with my Wordpress settings? If I enter the URL:

index.php?pagename=member-profile&profile=test

I'm forwarded to:

membership/member-profile/?pagename=member-profile&profile=test

Which returns a 404 error.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm pretty new to this Wordpress stuff and maybe I'm jumping in a bit too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'membership/member-profile/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=member-profile&profile=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

should be:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'membership/member-profile/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=membership/member-profile&profile=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

the difference is `pagename` should contain the parent/child path.

also- if `profile` isn't a recognized query var, it needs to be added in order to be accessed:

```
function wpse47596_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'profile';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse47596_query_vars' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the parent fixed my problem and the value is even showing up.